# problem with install symfony framework on hostmonster shared hosting server

Tags: frameworks, symfony1, installation, hostmonster

I'm trying to install symfony framework on my hostmonster shared hosting server.
but I'm in stock in "Configuring the Web Server" Part.
//http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_0/03-running-symfony

I don't know how to command for the alias. Now when I trying to access my test symfony app.
404 error show up.

Please Help~~!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just be missing symbolic links, which can be configured using the following commands:

> ln -sf ~/symfony/data/web/sf
>   ~/Symfony_Projects/myproject/web/sf
>
> ln -sf
>   ~/Symfony_Projects/myproject/web/*
>   ~/myproject.com

However, it is difficult to understand exactly what your problem is, since you are not providing an error, or enough information.